# Updated to CRA 2.0 and now can't build - Out of memory

Tags: npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

My Yarn build is broken since updating to CRA 2.0.

Getting out of memory error, I've tried running with a bigger max memory and it's not making any difference.

Yarn start is fine, but yarn build gives the following error:

```
    <--- Last few GCs --->

[14692:000001A168B8CC30]   367561 ms: Mark-sweep 1245.1 (1430.7) -> 1244.8 (1433.2) MB, 4524.1 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[14692:000001A168B8CC30]   372188 ms: Mark-sweep 1244.8 (1433.2) -> 1244.8 (1387.7) MB, 4626.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[14692:000001A168B8CC30]   377070 ms: Mark-sweep 1244.8 (1387.7) -> 1244.8 (1378.2) MB, 4882.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 00000117FCAA57C1 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: stringify(this=00000117FCA88FF1 <Object map = 0000015BE0D02BA1>,000002A6D8C022D1 <undefined>,000002A6D8C022D1 <undefined>,00000025F91DAB39 <Object map = 0000016E6AF79681>)
    1: arguments adaptor frame: 1->3
    2: _send [internal/child_process.js:675] [bytecode=0000024FC7AFB9B1 offset=551](this=0000037EBD602981 <process map = 0000015BE0D0A341>,message=00000025F91D...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString
 5: v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint
 6: v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts
 7: v8::internal::wasm::LocalDeclEncoder::Size
 8: v8::internal::wasm::LocalDeclEncoder::Size
 9: v8::internal::wasm::LocalDeclEncoder::Size
10: v8::internal::wasm::LocalDeclEncoder::Size
11: v8::internal::wasm::LocalDeclEncoder::Size
12: v8_inspector::protocol::Debugger::API::SearchMatch::fromJSONString
13: v8_inspector::protocol::Debugger::API::SearchMatch::fromJSONString
14: 00000178DC106B21
```

I'm not sure what else has changed to for this to fire.. i.e. what it's trying to stringify that is running out of memory.

Build scripts'

```
 "build": "npm run pre:build && react-app-rewired build && npm run post:build",
    "pre:build": "yarn run build:css && rimraf build && rimraf mobile/www/app/*",
    "post:build": "cp build/index.html mobile/www/ && cp build/* mobile/www/app --recursive",
```

Dev dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "16.4.13",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cra-build-watch": "^1.0.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.6",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
    "sinon": "^4.1.2",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "customize-cra": "^0.1.1"
  },
```

Comment: hi, did you solve this?

Comment: Hi, yes, but I can't remember how.. sorry I should have put an answer. It was likely another dependency I think I recall.

Comment: thanks @beek - I ended up restarting my PC, which cleared out the data. (The old "turn it off, turn it back on again" trick.) I had already tried reinstalling yarn.